# React Logo change does not apply to links with local href

Tags: reactjs, favicon

I'm trying to update the favicon logo in a project I created using create-react-app. I updated the logo name in index.html and the manifest.json, and the logo changes fine!

I have some links (`<a>`) inside the page and each will load a pdf file from the /public folder in a new tab (see example below). For these new tabs, I still see the React icon (the default blue atom favicon).

Does anyone know how I can fix this problem?

Example of how I'm using the link:

```
<a target = "_blank" href={require(`../public/pdfs/${item.nickname}.pdf`)}>
```

My manifest.json file (logo.png is my new logo):

```
{
  "short_name": "React App",
  "name": "Create React App Sample",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "logo.png",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

and the link in the header of index.html:

```
<link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo.png" />
```

Comment: Could you try it in incognito, or on other browsers?

Comment: @KennyJohnJacob I only have Safari and Chrome. Same result in both and Chrome incognito mode.

Comment: After running the _npm run build_ command and deploying it to the server, the pdf logo changes to the default grey globe Chrome shows when there is no favicon.

Comment: So the issue is only on localhost, you should be fine if so

Comment: True. I don't know if it's the default behaviour to show no logo for pdf files. If that's not the case, I still have the same problem.